# Grouping different values in a column and creating a new column in R (Similar to AS in SQL)

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, grouping, aggregate

new to R. I've been trying to find an answer to my question for the past hour or so but couldn't so I'll ask it here. I want to group some of the variables in a column and store that in a new column. I'll try to explain better with an example:

Suppose I have a data set called Animals.

```
Animal_type  Name
  Lion       Leo
  Tiger      Tigre
  Lion       Leon
  Dog        Rex
  Hyena      Sid
```

So what I'm basically trying to do is try to group the Animal Types into a more common group such as "Big Cats". I'm using tidyverse and I have tried this but it didn't work:

```
   Animals <- Animals %>% mutate(Species = ifelse('Animal_Type' == 
"Lion" | 'Animal_Type' == "Tiger", "Big_Cat", ifelse('Animal_Type' == 
"Dog" | 'Animal_Type' == "Hyena", "Big_Dog", "Other_Animal")))
```

However, this doesn't work and changes everything to Other_Animal. The animal_type was of class factor, but the issue wasn't fixed after I tried it after changing the class of animal_type to character. This is probably very easy, but I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: You can use `dplyr` to accomplish it: `library(dplyr)` and then  `df %>%  mutate(Species = if_else(Animal_type %in% c("Lion", "Tiger"), "Big_Cat", if_else(Animal_type %in% c("Dog", "Hyena"), "Big_Dog",  "Other_Animal")))`

Answer (score 0):

R is case sensitive for names.
In data 'Animal_type' with small 't', but in code with upper case 'T'.
And variables used without quotes in mutate.
So following code works:

```
Animals <- Animals %>% mutate(Species = ifelse(Animal_type ==  "Lion" | Animal_type == "Tiger", "Big_Cat", 
                                    ifelse(Animal_type ==   "Dog" | Animal_type == "Hyena", "Big_Dog", 
                                           "Other_Animal")))
```

Comment: I just made the example up here. The code I used for the original data I'm working with didn't have any typos. The above solution worked though :)

Comment: Great, just be careful with names :)